# Base64 string format in python

Tags: python, base64, string-formatting

I'm having an issue figuring out how to properly input base64 data into a string format in python 2.7. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
fileExec = open(fileLocation, 'w+')
fileExec.write(base64.b64decode('%s')) %(encodedFile) # encodedFile is base64 data of a file grabbed earlier in the script.
fileExec.close()
os.startfile(fileLocation)
```

As silly as it may seem, **I am required to use the string formatting in this case**, due to the what this script is actually doing, but when I launch the script, I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: Incorrect Padding
```

I'm not quite sure what I need to do to the '%s' to get this to work. Any suggestions? Am I using the wrong string format?

Update: Here's a better idea of what I'm ultimately trying to accomplish:

```
encodedFile = randomString() # generates a random string for the variable name to be written 
fileExec = randomString()
... snip ...
writtenScript += "\t%s.write(base64.b64decode(%s))\n" %(fileExec, encodedFile) # where writtenScript is the contents of the .py file that we are dynamically generating
```

I must use string formatting because the variable name will not always be the same in the python file we making.

Comment: You don't need to use string formatting at all: `b64decode(encodedFile)`

Comment: Also, it seems like you should be getting an error on the `fileExec.write(base64.b64decode('%s')) %(encodedFile)` line because the file `write()` method returns `None` which would result in a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %` exception.

Comment: While normally I wouldn't use string formatting, I am required to do it in this case because this script is writing to another script and the actual 'encodedFile' variable name will be randomly generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error usually means your base64 string may not be encoded properly. But here it is just a side-effect of a logic error in your code.
What you have done is basically this:

```
a = base64.b64decode('%s')
b = fileExec.write(a)
c = b % (encodedFile)
```

So you are attempting to decode the literal string "%s", which fails.

It should look more like this:

```
fileExec.write(base64.b64decode(encodedFile))
```

[edit: using redundant string format... pls don't do this in real code]

```
fileExec.write(base64.b64decode("%s" % encodedFile))
```

Your updated question shows that the b64decode part is inside of a string, not in your code. That is a significant difference. The code in your string is also missing a set of inner quotes around the second format:

```
writtenScript += "\t%s.write(base64.b64decode('%s'))\n" % (fileExec, encodedFile)
```

(notice the single quotes...)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am required to use string formatting in this case. Writing it as base64.b64decode(encodedFile) is not an option. Is there a way to have "encodedFile" called via some sort of format?

Comment: why are you "required"? it doesn't make any sense to do that in this case, it's entirely redundant.  That being said, you need to change the order of operations, above I showed you what you current order is (you're trying to format the return value of File.write, which is always None btw)

Comment: @Ondaje you are very confused about the mechanics of what is going on in your code. You need to take a step back and give more detail about what you're trying to accomplish, because it isn't going to be anything at all similar to what you've started with.

Comment: Your updated question shows that the b64decode part is inside of a string, not in your code. That is a significant difference.

Comment: My apologies. I was using the first portion as a way to debug what was going on. I should have just posted the updated portion to begin with.